# Is it possible to pass session data across domains with multiple Google Property IDs?

Tags: google-analytics

My situation is that I need to track data from:

Domain A with Google Property ID UA-XXXXXX-1

to

Domain B with Google Property ID UA-YYYYYY-2

Problem is, I need to be able to track the source of traffic to Domain A (organic, campaign, referral etc) in the Google Analytics property for Domain B.

As in, if i'm viewing data for a page in Domain B, i'd like to be able to see that the user originally found the referring page on Domain A via an email campaign using a UTM parameter.

Cross domain tracking is enabled on Domain A with Domain B set as an autoLink domain.

Question is, on the link from Domain A to Domain B, is their any way I can "push" the session data captured by UA-XXXXXX-1 across into Domain B so that it can be pushed to UA-YYYYYY-2?

I know the simplest solution to this is to add UA-YYYYYY-2 to Domain A, but that isn't an option.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try saving in cookie the source and medium on Domain A when user landed (based on document referrer) then add them as UTM parameters in querystring on all URLs from A to B. However, in this way you can know the source/medium but user and session will be different from the domain A.